# Using Komodo Edit, and trying to link HTML/CSS Files

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, external, komodoedit

I'm completely new at HTML/CSS.
I'm currently using a Mac and I don't know how to link HTML/CSS files in Komodo. Oddly enough, I cannot find anything online that explains how. Is there any one who can explain in DETAIL how to go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You link a CSS file with a `<link>` tag in the `<head>` of your HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
```

You can find more information from the [HTML Dog: Applying CSS article](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/applyingcss/).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm explaining this correctly, but I'm currently using two separate files- index.html and style.css. I'm still very confused with the linking process.

Comment: make sure they are both saved in the same directory(folder)

Comment: Thank you both for your helpful answers. ^_^